# How to calculate the GCD?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, mobius-function

How to evaluate the following with the help of Mobius function ?

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  \sum_{j=i+1}^n     \sum_{k=j+1}^n   \sum_{l=k+1}^n  {gcd(i,j,k,l)^4} .$$

In other words, we have to select all possible quadruplets from (1 ton n), and then sum up their value with power 4.

Example:-

N=4 :

(1,2,3,4) :   gcd(1,2,3,4)^4 = 1

Total sum = 1

For Second  Case, let N=5 :

(1,2,3,4) :   gcd(1,2,3,4)^4 = 1

(1,2,3,5) :   gcd(1,2,3,5)^4 = 1

(1,2,4,5) :   gcd(1,2,4,5)^4 = 1

(1,3,4,5) :   gcd(1,3,4,5)^4 = 1

(2,3,4,5) :   gcd(2,3,4,5)^4 = 1

Total sum = 1+1+1+1+1 = 5.

My approach is:
To calculate the number of quadruplets with gcd=2,3,4,...till n.

Say, the number of quadruplets with gcd=2 are x1, for gcd=3, its x2...and so on.

Now,  l  = $$\binom{n}{4}$$-(x1+x2+.......xn-1) = number of quadruplets with gcd=1.

Now, the final answer = l^4+x1^4+x2^4+.....

The only problem I have is how to calculate the number of quadruplets with gcd=x with the help of mobius function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sets of quadruples of integers $$Q(n)=\{(i,j,k,l) : 1\leqslant i<j<k<l\leqslant n\},\\ Q(n,d)=\{(i,j,k,l)\in Q(n) : \gcd(i,j,k,l)=d\}$$ for $1\leqslant d\leqslant n$. Clearly we have $$|Q(n)|=\binom{n}{4},\quad Q(n)=\bigcup_{d=1}^{n}Q(n,d),\quad Q(n,d)=dQ(\lfloor n/d\rfloor,1)$$
(where, for the last one, $d(i,j,k,l):=(di,dj,dk,dl)$ and $dS:=\{ds : s\in S\}$ are assumed).

This means that if $F(n)=|Q(n,1)|$, then $|Q(n,d)|=F(\lfloor n/d\rfloor)$ and $$\color{blue}{\sum_{d=1}^{n}F(\lfloor n/d\rfloor)=\binom{n}{4}}\quad\implies\quad F(n)=\sum_{d=1}^{n}\mu(d)\binom{\lfloor n/d\rfloor}{4}$$
by [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations). The sum we need is $S(n)=\sum\limits_{d=1}^{n}d^4 F(\lfloor n/d\rfloor)$. To compute it, one may avoid the computation of $\mu$, using the "blue" equation above as a recurrence for $F(n)$, and grouping terms with equal $\lfloor n/d\rfloor$ (here are my answers suggesting this too: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3240630/543769), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3200918/543769), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3059033/543769)).

Comment: I am very new to the concept of mobius inversion. Can you explain the part on how to calculate the last summation. And what is the meaning of [n/d]..does it mean the greatest integer function?

Comment: The correct answer for n=8 is 85 but your formula gives 69 :(

Comment: What do you do [n/d] becomes less than 4 ?

Comment: I am waiting @metamorphy.

Comment: F(8)= (8 C 4)*1 + (-1)*(4 C 4) + 0+0....= 69. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $F(8)=69$ but the sum you need is $S(8)=F(8)+16F(4)$ (+zeros).

Comment: Ooh..I got it . Tysm.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273070/how-to-calculate-the-value-of-this-function @metamorphy Can you solve this recurrence relation ?

Comment: @metamorphy what if we have to answer the sum for all n from 1 to something like maybe, 1 to 10^3 ? Calculating for every n is gonna take O(n^2). Something better?

Comment: @resound I would try switching the order of summation, starting with either $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m}\sum\limits_{d=1}^{n}d^4F(\lfloor n/d\rfloor)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}[\ldots]F(k)$ (with a closed form of $[\ldots]$, perhaps complicated but manageable), or directly with the defining sum at the top. Details are worth a dedicated question I think.

Comment: @metamorphy Have asked the same question as was very curious. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

A quadruplet with gcd a multiple of $d$ occurs iff all $i,j,k,l$ are multiples of $d$, for which there are ${\lfloor n/d\rfloor\choose d}$ possibilities.
So you'll arrive at
$${n\choose 4}\cdot 1^4+{\lfloor n/2\rfloor\choose 4}\cdot (2^4-1^4) +{\lfloor n/3\rfloor\choose 4}\cdot (3^4-1^4)+{\lfloor n/4\rfloor\choose 4}\cdot (4^4-2^4)+\cdots$$

Comment: You should give a formula for the general term, since it's not clear to someone who doesn't already know the answer.

Comment: @GregMartin Can you explain the answer in a bit more detail and give me the general formula ?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen     For n=6, answer is 15, and your formula gives answer as '5'. It is incorrect.

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon Look carefully, the answer does come 15 for $n=6$